# How can I pass a variable from one Python Script to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I am trying to pass a variable with a filename/location from one Python file to another on Python 3.6.8.**

I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

executor.py (*this file is the first file, ran by the user*) I enter code.ntx because that is the file I want to use [I don't need to put the C:\ stuff because my file is in the same folder as the executor.py]:

```py
print('What file would you like to open? (ex. C:\\Users\\JohnDoe\\Documents\\helloworld.ntx): ')
filename = input()
print('Loading ' + filename + '...')

import nitrix001
```

nitrix001.py code (well the parts that matter for this)

```py
from __main__ import *

if filename == " ":
    # The user can set this to the name of the file.
    filename = "lang.ntx"
# Opens the actual file. We use this in the 'for' loop.
File = open(f"{filename}", "r")
#
Characters = ''
# Integer that indicates the line of the program the language is reading.
Line = 1
# Variable that checks if the program is currently inside parantheses.
args = False

# Runs a 'for' loop on each line of the file.
for LineData in File:
    print(f'\nRunning Line {Line}: {LineData}')
    if not LineData.startswith('#'):
```

When I run that executor.py and fill in the input with code.ntx I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import executor
  File "/home/runner/executor.py", line 16, in <module>
    import nitrix001
  File "/home/runner/nitrix001.py", line 3, in <module>
    if filename == " ":
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined
```

Comment: have you tried to make a def in the second file, import that def and call using the filename as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this. Build a real interface and import it, don't use `import` to run an executable script.

```py
# executor.py
filename = input("...")

import nitrix001

nitrix001.main(filename)
```

```py
# nitrix001
def main(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

@William

I don't know an way to do what you are trying to achieve. I would use functions instead

```
print('What file would you like to open? (ex. C:\\Users\\JohnDoe\\Documents\\helloworld.ntx): ')
filename = input()
print('Loading ' + filename + '...')

from nitrix001 import myfunc
myfunc(filename)
```

and then on nitrix001.py:

```
def myfunc(filename)
    if filename == " ":
        # The user can set this to the name of the file.
        filename = "lang.ntx"
    # Opens the actual file. We use this in the 'for' loop.
    File = open(f"{filename}", "r")
    #
    Characters = ''
    # Integer that indicates the line of the program the language is reading.
    Line = 1
    # Variable that checks if the program is currently inside parantheses.
    args = False

    # Runs a 'for' loop on each line of the file.
    for LineData in File:
        print(f'\nRunning Line {Line}: {LineData}')
        if not LineData.startswith('#'):
```

Answer (score 0):

This is generally not good practice for passing variables between files, in fact what you’re trying to do is steal `__main__`'s global variables thus kind of the opposite of being passed plus you get all variables and not just filename.

What you should do is import the second file at the top of the first script. In that second file have a function with parameters you’d like passed in. Then you can call that function from the main script.

executor.py

```
import nitrix001

filename = input('What file would you like to open? ')
print('Loading ' + filename + '...')

nitrix001.run(filename)
```

nitrix001.py

```
def run(filename):
    #do work with the file
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to do the same for the code of the first file.

Comment: I’m unsure what you mean